# While Upgrade Ubuntu trhowa this unmet dependencies error every time

Tags: 18.04, upgrade

You might want to run `apt --fix-broken install` to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
 libc6-dbg : Depends: libc6 (= 2.27-3ubuntu1.2) but 2.27-3ubuntu1 is installed
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.27-3ubuntu1.2) but 2.27-3ubuntu1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Steps that I had tried

- -fix-borken
- -force-update
- -force-overright
- -Autoclean

Comment: Did you try `sudo apt update` first ?

Comment: Yes, Already tried

Comment: What architecture are you on?  (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=libc6) and have you checked your used mirror is *up-to-date* (https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors)

Comment: You can try reinstalling those two files `sudo apt install --reinstall libc6-dbg libc6-dev` or remove both and reinstall them.  18.04 is showing those both as version `2.27-3ubuntu1.2` from the `bionic-updates main` and `bionic-security main` respositories.

Comment: @Terrance, Tried with Install and Un-Installed throws same error

Comment: @guiverc Ubuntu Architeure is : uname x86_64, and Mirrro is 2 days back

Comment: Make sure that in the `Software & Updates` in the `Updates` tab that both the `Security` and `Updates` are enabled.  Then remove them both `sudo apt remove libc6-dbg libc6-dev` then reinstall them `sudo apt install libc6-dbg libc6-dev`.  They should install the correct version at that point.  If they don't, look into using a different repository from a different server by setting one in `Software & Updates` under the `Ubuntu Software` tab.  Also, please make sure that you are copying and pasting your terminal with any errors to your question.

Comment: @Terrance  While enabling `Security` and `Updates` E: The throws error  `repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu`

Comment: @Terrance any other solution apart from form formatting OS, any help will appreciate

Comment: If it is giving incomplete error messages sounds like something is indeed messed up. I would try rebooting the system to Recovery Mode, then choose the Check For Errors fsck, or something like that from the menu.